# using edm Number Mapping

Tags: entity-framework, oracle11g, entity-framework-6

In my Oracle database I have a field that has a datatype as Number(3). When I add a edm model and tell it to use code first from database, the model comes back on the .net side as a byte

```
    public byte Quantity { get; set; }
```

I have tried to use the edmNumberMapping tag in the web.config, but it never changes the type when the model is built. Here is the number mapping.

```
<edmMappings>
    <edmNumberMapping>
        <add NETType="bool" MinPrecision="1" MaxPrecision="1" DBType="Number" />
        <add NETType="int" MinPrecision="2" MaxPrecision="5" DBType="Number" />
        <add NETType="int32" MinPrecision="6" MaxPrecision="10" DBType="Number" />
        <add NETType="int64" MinPrecision="11" MaxPrecision="19" DBType="Number" />
    </edmNumberMapping>
</edmMappings>
```

I'm trying to get the Quantity field in the database to come back as an int data type. I have read other questions and it seems like a lot of people are having the same issue. Has anyone figured this out yet? Or can tell me what else I can try? VS2015, Oracle 11g, and entity framework 6.

Comment: Do you have your edmx in your web application or is it in a diff project?

Comment: @RacielR. when I originally did this, I didn't use an .edmx file. I would right click the Models folder and select add ADO.NET Entity Data Model, from there I would select Code First from database. I did start a new project and this time selected EF Designer from database, and it did create an .edmx file. Even with the .edmx file, it still didn't convert my Number(3) field over to an int. This is all in one project also. This isn't a deal breaker, it would just be nice to be able to configure this.